# Is it redundant to say "I do that everyday as my mom asks me do that"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, redundancy

A friend and I talked about chores at home, I said

> I hate doing the dishes though I do that everyday as my mom asks me do that.

I'm pretty sure the part before "though" is idiomatic as [Google returns plenty of hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hate%20doing%20the%20dishes%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=%22hate%20doing%20the%20dishes%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2516j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for it.

The question is whether the part after "though" sounds redundant? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion:
`I hate doing the dishes, though I do them every day, as my Mom asks me to.`

This corrects the spelling error of "every day", pointed out in the comment.
"doing them" accords better with "doing the dishes" than "do that".
The last "do that" is redundant and can be dropped entirely.

Comment: I'd think **but** would be a more natural conjunction here than **though**. "Because" or "since" could also stand in for "as." +1 for the other points.

Comment: @TypeIA  If you read "as" as "since" or "because",  then those would be better choices, I agree. However, the "as" could mean "in accordance with my Mom's wishes". But that's a fine point, since it doesn't change the meaning much, If you wanted to unambiguously say "in accordance" you could use "just as my Mom asks me to." Bottom line, I agree with you.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean about the distinction. I think I would say "... **like** my mom asks me to" to indicate compliance. There are lots of options.